# ibatis 1.6.2 for .Net query timeout

Tags: .net, ado.net, timeout, ibatis

Is there a way to set the query timeout for ibatis 1.6 on the .net platform?

Unfortunately, upgrading is not an option for me in this case.

Cheers
Shane

Answer (score 2):

I've done this using the decorator pattern that decorates the IDbProvider to expose the needed method:

```
public abstract class LongQueriesDecorator : IDbProvider
{
    protected IDbProvider _iDbProvider;

    public void setDbProvider(IDbProvider iDbProvider)
    {
        this._iDbProvider = iDbProvider;
    }


    public abstract void setCommandTimeout(IDbCommand cmd);

    // implement all IDbProvider methods calling _iDbProvider.METHOD
    // ...
    // except for

    public IDbCommand CreateCommand()
    {
        if (_iDbProvider != null)
        {
            IDbCommand cmd = _iDbProvider.CreateCommand();
            // here you can call the delegate
            setCommandTimeout(cmd);
            return cmd;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then realize the abstract class:

```
public class LongQueries : LongQueriesDecorator
{
    public override void setCommandTimeout(IDbCommand cmd)
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;  // here you can configure a value in the App.config
    }
}
```

And finally when you build the mapper:

```
        _mapper = builder.Configure(sqlMapConfig);
        LongQueries lq = new LongQueries();
        lq.setDbProvider(_mapper.DataSource.DbProvider);
        _mapper.DataSource.DbProvider = lq;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. In my case my ibatis is wrapped by another third party api, so I may or may not be able to plug in custom code like this. Cheers, Shane